# How to change the odc connection file paths in excel using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, odbc, oledb

I have an excel file (embedded resource in a c# project) with multiple worksheets which get their data from SQL Server using connection information from odc file.  I want to update the excel file to look for these odc files in a specific folder which I specify, so need to update the excel odc connection file path accordingly.  How can I do this via c#, so for example, if I output the odc file to "d:\odcFiles\abc.odc", then I want to update the excel connection path to "d\odcFiles\abc.odc".  Likewise for all other odc files.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

The highlighted part is what I am referring to (location of the odc file), which I would like to change on the fly via c#:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way, probably the simplest way, would be to edit the registry directly.

[Update]
I don't know about ODBC.  But I've used this code to dynamically access excel files.  It was for an asp.net app but the important DB stuff is there.

```
// using System.Data.OleDb
OleDbConnection ExcelConection = null;
OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = null;
OleDbDataReader ExcelReader = null;
OleDbConnectionStringBuilder OleStringBuilder = null;

try
{
    OleStringBuilder =
        new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';");
    OleStringBuilder.DataSource = MapPath(@"~\App_Datav\MyExcelWorksheet.xls");

    ExcelConection = new OleDbConnection();
    ExcelConection.ConnectionString = OleStringBuilder.ConnectionString;

    ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    ExcelCommand.Connection = ExcelConection;
    ExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

    ExcelConection.Open();
    ExcelReader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = ExcelReader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception Args)
{
    LabelErrorMsg.Text = "Could not open Excel file: " + Args.Message;
}
finally
{
    if (ExcelCommand != null)
        ExcelCommand.Dispose();
    if (ExcelReader != null)
        ExcelReader.Dispose();
    if (ExcelConection != null)
        ExcelConection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: How do you mean Steve?  The excel file is an embedded resource in a c# project and I would like to update the paths for all the reports on the fly and output the file to a user specified folder along with the odc files.

Comment: "The excel file is an embedded resource in a c# project..."  I didn't know that.  Perhaps you should update your question with that information.

Comment: Updated.  Any ideas on how to modify the excel file and update these odc file paths?

Comment: I updated my answer.  The fact that ODBC configuration is stored on the PC and the excel file is embedded in your application is...problematic (to my way of thinking).

Comment: Thanks Steve for the help, but I don't think there is a clean way to do what I am trying to do, so I have resorted to creating the odc files with a specific path and then outputting the odc files to that path, so the excel file can always find them when looking at it's data connection file path.

Comment: Any other suggestions/workarounds would be highly appreciated.